# Zipping a list in thread-safe manner

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

At the moment, I am using the following pseudo-code:

```
List<MyMail> m = new List<MyMail>();
foreach(var user in users) {
    var mails = mailLibrary.getAllMails(user); // synchronously; 100ms waiting time
    foreach(var mail in mails) m.add(mail);
}
return m.ToArray();
```

Now I want to fetch mail of all users in parallel, since the mailLibrary is written synchronously, and multiple mail servers are involved.
Still, the list should be sorted the same way it was before. So I would try

```
List<MyMail> m = new List<MyMail>();
Parallel.ForEach(users,user => {
    List<MyMail> innerM = new List<MyMail>();
    var mails = mailLibrary.getAllMails(user); // synchronously; 100ms waiting time
    foreach(var mail in mails) innerM.add(mail);
    // How to zip innerM list content into m such that content is at the correct position?
});
return m.ToArray();
```

How can I zip `innerM` into `m` at the correct position?

Comment: What programming language is this? Tag accordingly

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered using Parallel LINQ instead?

```
return users.AsParallel().AsOrdered()
            .SelectMany(user => mailLibrary.getAllMails(user))
            .ToArray();
```

I *believe* that will do the right thing, in terms of maintaining all the ordering, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: If SelectMany is not supported with respect to preserving order, he can use Select and flatten later.

Comment: @usr: `SelectMany` is definitely supported; it's a matter of whether the ordering is exactly as required. The documentation leads me to suspect that it is.

Comment: @JonSkeet It does preserve the ordering in the original collection / enumerable, at least in every case that I've used it so far :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/LCkCb84p, it does preserve ordering as far as I've been able to test.